# Deploy a project that includes entity framework and sql server 2014

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-2014, installshield

I have Visual Studio 2015, and I am trying to create an installation package for a product of mine for selling purpose.

I have tried Installshield Limited Edition for Visual Studio but with that, the installer can't access the database on my client's computer.
i have installed sql server 2014 on client's computer and attatched the database file to it but i am faced with the following error

[image]

I am not sure how to add the Entity Framework library and SQL Server database as they are not picked up or accessed automatically.

Comment: Do you use EF or ADO.NET? They are completely different data-access technologies

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you can clearly see:

> .... Login failed for user 'SAWLAIN-PC...'

Your problem is a hard-coded connection string.

Comment: how can i manupulate my conection string on the client's computer without having visual studio?????

Comment: @SaqlainNawaz Either use the app.config or make the connection string dynamic

Comment: using entity model, the connection string is made according to my PC. thats why when it is installed on any other PC it gives this error. i'm not getting how to execute my project on that PC without having visualstudio. Please help me in this regard.... i'm stuck here for too long...

Comment: if i edit only the app.config file then i have to rebuild the solution on client's PC. for which i need the visual studio... which i hav'nt

Comment: @SaqlainNawaz No, completely incorrect. App.configis exactly there so you don't have to rebuild

Comment: @SaqlainNawaz *but still facing the same error*. After doing *what*? Did you do what Camilo suggested? I.e. install the application. Then edit the app.config on the client's machine and supply the correct connection string.